# Embedd the documentclass {article} in another Latex environment via .tex .dvi .ps

Tags: environments, embedding

I'm asked to embedd a Latex document into another one. The documentclass is an article. To me it was given the information to use latex instead of pdflatex to compile, after that it's a "threestep" [nnn].tex, dvips [nnn].dvi, ps2pdf [nnn].ps to get the wanted pdf. [nnn] stands for the documentname with the datatypes given to use. If the datatypes aren't unknown to you I'd be glad if you could tell me a link (e.g.) where I can find a way of solving this task. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: This exact same question has been asked a few days ago.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Basics#Historical_versions_of_LaTeX